# Why is "whatsoever" used here?

Tags: determiners

I've been into the use of "any" in positive sentences, and I crossed that this sense of "any" can also be used with "whatsoever" to add emphasis, such as:

- If you have any query whatsoever - it doesn't matter what it is -
  please ask me.

Nevertheless, I think that "whatsoever" is just used with negative sentences to add emphasis, and "any" in this sense is not indicating anything negative, so why is "whatsoever" used? and wouldn't it be better to use "whatever" instead?

Here is the link where I found that sentence: https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv303.shtml

Comment: ***whatsoever*** is an ***intensifier*** for preceding ***any** [query]* - it's only there to impress on the audience that the speaker doesn't mind if the "queries" are trivial or stupid (or in some other way not exactly "standard" - so long as they are actually "queries", that's good enough).

Comment: In the context as cited, [***whatever*** and ***whatsoever*** are equivalent and interchangeable.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+any+questions+whatever%2Chave+any+questions+whatsoever&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20any%20questions%20whatever%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20any%20questions%20whatsoever%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers it seems that nowadays "whatsoever" is less common in positive sentences, and it's just used in negative ones.

Comment: I think you're quite right that ***whatsoever*** (which [used to be very uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=none+whatever%2Cnone+whatsoever&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) compared to the shorter ***whatever***) works better in *syntactically* negating contexts. But I don't think it's necessarily relevant whether the *tone, meaning* of the utterance is positive or negative - it seems to me that the longer version has risen to prominence as the ***more emphatic*** choice.

Comment: (But nobody normally says *Frankly my dear, I don't give a damn. You just do **whatsoever** you want!*, no matter how emphatic they want to be :)

Answer (score 2):

> If you have any query whatsoever - it doesn't matter what it is - please ask me.

whatever = whatsoever (whatsoever's emphasis is greater than whatever's)

whatsoever is the stressed version of whatever

whatever is used frequently after nouns combined with **no, any, all**.

ex) There is no doubt whatever/whatsoever. Is there any chance whatever/whatsoever?

Comment: Got it! But I think that this use of "whatsoever" instead of "whatever" meaning any kind of something is archaic. And just nowadays native speakers just use whatsoever in negative sentences. Source: https://www.allearsenglish.com/aee-812-use-whatsoever-want-emphasize-something-negative-statement/